# Connect continuously websocket into local wamp server?

Tags: php, websocket, codeigniter-3, cron-task, ratchet

I have implement rachet websocket with codeigniter and it's working fine in localhost. This is a main server.php that we need to run from cmd

```
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

use Chat\Chat;

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)), 2000);

$server->run();
```

I run this file from cmd with following command

`D:\wamp\www\my_project\api\application\third_party\Realtime\bin server.php`

This command start socket and now any user access my site through browser then they are connect with socket and i can sent message to him. When i close cmd then socket close automatic.

How can i connect with this socekt continuously without run server.php from cmd ?
Is any way to create any confing file so using that we can do it ? I try this http://socketo.me/docs/deploy but this is for linux i am using windows (Wamp)

Comment: You can't, that's why you need a web server.

Comment: Then how it works on live site ? If i have shared hosting then how can i start webserver continuously ?

Comment: Shared hosts usually don't allow long running processes.